# How do I get my program to only accept certain inputs in python 2.x

Tags: python-2.7, input, python-2.x

I would like this program to only accept as inputted text any of `"yes ,"y", "Yes"` but for some reason when I input one of them nothing happens and the loop below doesn't seem to run:

```
import time

print ("Welcome to my first ever RPG! created 10/07/2016")
time.sleep(2)
begin = raw_input("Would you like to start the game?")

Start = False

if begin == ("yes" , "y" , "Yes" ):
    Start == True        

while Start == True:   
    player_name = raw_input("What would you like to name your character")
    print ("welcome " + player_name.capitalize())
```

(PS: simplest solution preferred, I'm sort of new to python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with your original solution and just change it like so (not recommended):

```
if begin.strip() == "yes" or begin.strip() == "y" or begin.strip() == "Yes":
```

Or just check for containment in a tuple:

```
if begin.strip() in ("yes" , "y" , "Yes" ):
```

Or even better:

```
if begin.strip().lower().startswith('y'):
```

The `.strip()` deals with any whitespace the user may have inputted.

And you also want to change

```
Start == True
```

to

```
Start = True
```

Because the former line is an equality test rather than assignment, so in your case `Start` is always False.

Comment: `if begin.strip().lower().startswith('y'):` will match any word starting with "y"...

Comment: @jDo Yup, but it's a simple enough program, figured might as well eh

Answer (score 1):

`begin` is a string and `("yes" , "y" , "Yes" )` is a tuple. Thus, `begin == ("yes" , "y" , "Yes" )` will never be true. However, there are three strings in the tuple which can be compared to `begin`. The verbose way of doing that would be to write:

```
for element in ("yes" , "y" , "Yes" ):
    if element == begin:
        Start = True
```

Python has a handy way of doing this operation in fewer lines of code using the `in` keyword:

```
if begin in ("yes" , "y" , "Yes" ):
    Start = True
```

Note that I also changed `Start == True` to `Start = True` since `==` is only for comparison and here you probably want an assignment which is done using `=`.

To catch more variations of the user input ("Yes", "YES", "yES", "y", "Y", etc.):

```
begin = begin.strip().lower()
if begin in ("y", "yes"):
    Start = True
```